# Fetching values from nested list using Adapter

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am getting data from server in json

[image]

I am using a custom adapter and storing showing this data on the recyclerview

i am using the Getter Setter class to to get and set values
this is my class of Getter Setter

```
public class UserData {
String email,firstName;
List<String> companies;

public UserData(String email, String firstName, List<String> companies) {
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.companies = companies;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public List<String> getCompanies() {
    return companies;
}

public void setCompanies(List<String> companies) {
    this.companies = companies;
}
```

}

By using the adapter class i am able to show the email and firstName but not able to get data from companies 
Code for getting the data

```
final UserData rowItem = rowItems.get(position);
holder.tvName.setText(rowItem.getfirstName());
holder.tvEmail.setText(rowItem.getemail());
```

I want to show  companies list also

holder.tvCompanies.setText(strCompaniesName);
i am using this to get the companies names of the users

```
strCompaniesName = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < rowItem.getCompanies().size(); i++) {

            Log.i("Value of element " + i, rowItem.getCompanies().get(i));
            if (i == 0)
                strCompaniesName = rowItem.getCompanies().get(i);
            else
                strCompaniesName = strCompaniesName + ", \n " + rowItem.getCompanies().get(i);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your code that convert `json` to `UserData` object? Also the `adapter` code.

Comment: What does logcat show?